# Exception handling with aspect oriented programming

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, aspect

I am new to Aspect-oriented programming. I am working on a spring-boot application with AspectJ, that has already an exception handling aspect as follows:

```
@Aspect
@Order(0)
public class ExceptionAspect {
 

  public ExceptionAspect() {
  }

  @Pointcut("within(com.mycom.service.impl..*)")
  public void applicationServicePointcut() {
  }

  @AfterThrowing(
    pointcut = "applicationServicePointcut()",
    throwing = "e"
  )
  public void translate(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
    ...
     //EXCEPTION HANDLING LOGIC
  }
}
```

Now I would like to add one more aspect, say `NewAspect` for the same pointcut as mentioned above i.e.

```
  "within(com.mycom.service.impl..*)"
```

Also I want any exception happening in the `NewAspect` to be handled by the `ExceptionAspect`.

In this regard, I am not able to understand, if the `Order` of the new aspect should be more than the existing `ExceptionAspect` or not.

Comment: Are you really using native AspectJ, or is it rather proxy-based Spring AOP? My answer to your question depends on it. BTW, you cannot do exception handling inside an `@AfterThrowing` advice, only in an `@Around` advice. The only thing you can do in your case are actions which do not stop the exception from being thrown up the call stack, such as logging the exception. Logging is not handling.

Comment: @kriegaex I am using native AspectJ. Sure, I will refactor the exception handling aspect as you suggested. Could you please suggest regarding the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Order` annotation or implementing the `@Ordered` interface are Spring-specific and therefore only have an effect on Spring-managed components. AspectJ is a product independent of Spring. It has its own way of declaring and handling precedence:

- Search the [AspectJ programming guide](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/printable.html) for the terms "precedence" in general and the `declare precedence` statement in particular.
- While the former document explains the basics and how to declare precedence in native AspectJ syntax, please search the [AspectJ 5 developer's notebook](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/printable.html) for `@DeclarePrecedence` in order to learn about an annotation-syntax alternative.

P.S.: I asked whether you use native AspectJ or Spring AOP because of the ordering annotations and also because in Spring AOP one aspect cannot advise another one. So what you want is only possible in native AspectJ in the first place.